# Gradle Plugin not found

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, onesignal

When I try to compile my project with

```
react-native run-android
```

It keeps returning me this:

> JS server already running.
>
> Building and installing the app on the device (cd android &&
>   gradlew.bat installDebug)...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\Gabriele\Documents\reactnative\educarnival\android\app\build.gradle'
>     line: 9
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > Plugin with id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' not found.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 5.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s Could not install the app on the device, read the
>   error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

**At first** I thought it had something to do with the plugin, but actually after short research on the internet, I discovered that this could be related to Gradle Maintenance. I just want your opinion, **is there a way I can solve this?**

My app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.educarnival"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 23
        versionName "2.7.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true  // needed for firestore
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'a7535fcc-58f4-412f-97ee-a21264a1607d',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
        // Add support for vector drawables for Android pre-lollipop devices
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    compile project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'

    // Multidex support for Android pre-lollipop devices
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2"

    // Crashlytics dependency
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: What version of Gradle you are using?

Comment: I installed 6.1 right now but the project is using gradle 3.2.0

Comment: Try to comment `apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'` in `build.gradle` file.

Comment: seems like gradle is under maintenance https://status.gradle.com/

Comment: Oh..so should I wait 'til they finish? I hoped that the problem was on my side, I don't know when they will end maintaining it and I'm in a hurry :ç (Already have apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' in build.gradle)

Comment: just try to exclude this plugin temporary (as I described). Usually doing maintenance quickly

Comment: excluding that line and compiling it returns me this with an error: * What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory C:\Users\Gabriele\Documents\reactnative\educarnival\node_modules\react-native-camera\android\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\org\reactnative.
> Unable to delete directory C:\Users\Gabriele\Documents\reactnative\educarnival\node_modules\react-native-camera\android\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\org\reactnative.

Comment: delete node_modules folder and re-install packages (npm install or yarn install)

Comment: Oook it did the trick! The app installed and started but now shows a Java Exception in 'NativeModules'. I'm trying to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206077/discussion-between-gabriele-cina-and-demkovych).

Comment: I edited the question, now there's also the app/build.gradle file

Comment: did you check they documentation? https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android

Comment: I think you have a problem with android studio or wrong onesignal version. Can't reproduce it on my pc

Comment: mmm...android studio? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the classpath found in [plugin class path](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/onesignal/androidsdk/GradleProjectPlugin.groovy) (without quotes)

```
 apply plugin: com.onesignal.androidsdk.GradleProjectPlugin
```

instead of

```
plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question `JS server already running.` I discovered that this line appears when you already have a JS server running which is of another application. And you are trying to run the your current application with packager of another application.

Check for any previously opened packagers or Alternatively close all the terminals and rerun your application using `react-native run-android`

Comment: Hi Ajeett, thanks for your answer. I tried this and apparently nothing changes

Comment: Can you share your plugin details you are applying in your Gradle file

Comment: Hey! I edited the question, now there's also the app/build.gradle file